# Replace() query

Tags: str-replace, replace

I seen this code on a website

```
function filterPath(string) {
    return string
              .replace(/^\//,'')
              .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
              .replace(/\/$/,'');
}
```

The result of this gave some really long code in nos,digits, and slashes and couldn't figure it out. Is it like a security trick or something like that. 
I just cant seem to understand what is this "replace" function trying to achieve ?? If anyone could explain what does it mean...

Answer (score 0):

These are [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) (called regex for short).

The actual expression is inside `/.../` with `\` beeing an escape character. 
So `/^\//` holds an `^/` regex.

As for your exact expressions:

**1.** `^/`: the `/` character at the begging of line (`^`)

**2.** `(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$`:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**3.** the `/$`: `/` character at the end of line (`$`)